# How to vertically center text

Tags: html, css

I want text centered vertically in a box. I don't want to use `padding-top`, because it will not be correct for text of every length. I have posted an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/55Ruh/23/

Comment: try this:  vertical-align:middle;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the table attribute **vertical-align** like this (on your example):

the html:

```
<div class="bg_class">
  <div class="bg_class_inner">
    My text goes here...My text goes here...My text goes here...
    My text goes here...My text goes here...My text goes here...
    My text goes here...My text goes here...My text goes here...
    My text goes here...My text goes here...
  </div>
</div>
```

the css:

```
.bg_class
{
  background: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table; 
}
.bg_class_inner
{
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle
}
```

Comment: It seems not to work when I use float right and left in `bg_class`

Comment: @hey: You use `float: left;` together with `margin: 0 auto;`?

Comment: `.bg_class
{
  background: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  float: left;
}` this one works fine, it puts the box to the left... I don`t know what you want to achieve by using float.